# How do I get R to recognise that there is a missing value in my dataframe, by inserting a "NA" into the empty cell?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've created the following data frame, DF, in R.

```
Data_point <- c('a','a','b','b','','c')
Measurement <- c(2,4,6,8,4,-10.4)

DF <- data.frame(Data_point, Measurement)
```

However DF is not showing any NAs in R, even though there is a missing value in the "Data_point" column. How can I get R to identify that there is a missing value in the "Data_point" column?

Comment: You created it as `""` instead of `NA`,  i.e. it should be `c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', NA, 'c')`

Comment: and `Data_point[Data_point==""] <- NA` if you can't fix it upstream

Comment: `na_if` from `dplyr` replaces any occurrences of a value with `NA`, such as `Data_point <- dplyr::na_if(Data_point, "")`

Comment: @akrun Okay, thanks. However if I don't have an NA in a missing cell, is there a way to check for missing values within a column, in a dataframe.

Comment: Please check the comment by @Moody_Mudskipper if the missing value is `""`

Comment: @akrun I see! Thanks!!